# Just how inexact is setInexactRepeating() for AlarmManager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I know this question has been asked before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129282/how-inexact-is-setinexactrepeating-for-alarmmanager), but the answer given refers to documentation which is actually incredibly ambiguous. It says the inexact alarm might occur almost a "full interval" after the specified time. For alarms with an interval of a whole day, this would seem excessive.

The documentation does say [here](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#set) (under "RTC examples") that you can use inexact repeating for daily alarms, and gives an example of an inexact alarm being set for "approximately 2pm". Nobody in their right mind would think "approximately 2pm" might mean 1pm the next day, so it doesn't seem likely daily alarms at least can be "almost a full interval" after the specified time.

Is there any definite info out there about just how late an inexact alarm with a daily interval might be? Thanks.

(I know API 19 has "setWindow" but I'd like my app to work on older APIs too).

Comment: `It says the inexact alarm might occur almost a "full interval" after the specified time`. You already have your answer.

Comment: This contradicts the example in the documentation of an alarm going off at "approximately 2pm". "Approximately 2pm" can't possibly mean 23 hours later!

Comment: Normally it won't. It tries to group alarms if in a reasonable closeness. If not, it will fire at a time the system finds comfortable (CPU / GC / ... other internal affairs it has to manage) - "approximately at the specified time". After all, it should be reasonably close to the time you set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How inexact is setInexactRepeating() for AlarmManager?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129282/how-inexact-is-setinexactrepeating-for-alarmmanager)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tested this with 5 consecutive alarms and the average delay, on my phone, was 11.8 minutes. This was with the interval between repeats set to INTERVAL_DAY.

Comment: Same here, 11.5 minutes average.

Answer (score 0):

Read here:

https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/alarms/schedule#inexact-after-specific-time

> On Android 12 (API level 31) and higher, the system invokes the alarm
> within one hour of the supplied trigger time, unless any
> battery-saving restrictions are in effect such as battery saver or
> Doze.

So this means that if you've set it to 10 minutes from now, it might reach 1:10 hours from now, maybe even more in special restrictions...

Even if you use a window, it says there that it can be delayed by at least (not at most) 10 minutes from this window:

> If your app calls setWindow(), the alarm never goes off before the
> supplied trigger time. Unless any battery-saving restrictions are in
> effect, the alarm is delivered within the specified time window,
> starting from the given trigger time.
>
> If your app targets Android 12 or higher, the system can delay the
> invocation of a time-windowed inexact alarm by at least 10 minutes.
> For this reason, windowLengthMillis parameter values under 600000 are
> clipped to 600000.