# Is there an accurate repeating-alarm system for Android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

## Background

---

I'm currently developing an application for Android which revolves around an alarm that goes of on an user specified time. My intent for it is that it will be used for waking people up in the morning (and the following morning - aka repeating alarm). When the alarm goes of it will call an `Activity` that has a couple of options (such as snooze). I've got all of this working but I'm running in to a problem.

## Problem

---

I'm using [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to handle my alarm needs. There is however something curious going on with the class (in my opinion). There are two adviced ways to handle the setting of the alarm time. Namely [`setInexactRepeating`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) and [`setRepeating`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29). The problem with these functions are:

- `setInexactRepeating` is not very accurate. My tests have shown that this gets approximately activated at the specified time, which the documentation indicates, all be it rather vaguely;

  > the alarm will not fire before this time, but there may be a delay of almost an entire alarm interval before the first invocation of the alarm.

  My tests show there is usually something of a 5 minute delay. On [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23777286/1294864) the user has an average delay of approximately 12 minutes.  This won't do, of course, for a system that is supposed to wake people up at their specified times.
- `setRepeating` does trigger at the specified time. The docs specify however that as of API 19 that all repeating alarms are inexact. Which is exactly what I don't want.

  > As of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. Because this method has been available since API 3, your application can safely call it and be assured that it will get similar behavior on both current and older versions of Android.

There is a [`setExact`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) method, but this is a bit too specific. Aside from that it does not give me the option to have a certain interval (for repeating the alarm daily). *Edit:* After trying to go with `setExact` I found that this would require me to move up to API 19 (currently on 15), which is something I would like to avoid.

## Question

---

Am I using the wrong class for this system? To me it seems like it should be a legit usage, but reading through the docs has left me wondering. Is there perhaps another class which is better suited for this system?

Comment: @MikeM. I meant that it's a function that may be a bit overkill. Kind of a waste of battery to use that. The caveat you refer to brings me back to the feeling that setExact is a bit too much overkill. I don't want the application to run at the _exact_ specified time perse. I don't mind if it fires 30 seconds later or so (just not a minute). I'm just wondering if I'm using the correct class, because non of the functions seem to fit very well (I'm looking for an inbetween function perhaps). Maybe I should just get over the feeling and use setExact ;)

Comment: @MikeM. Dang, just found that using `setExact` requires me to move up to API 19, which is something I would like to avoid. Is there really no other option as to use this class and/or its functions?

Comment: @MikeM. Learned something new. Didn't know you could check for different API levels and change your methods accordingly. Thanks :)

Comment: Got any working solution?

Comment: @droid_dev Unfortunately I'm quite swamped so I won't have time to type up an answer anytime soon. To get you on your way you can make an if-statement that checks the `android.os.Build.VERSION`. If it's equal or above `19` use the `exactRepeating`, if it's below use `setRepeating`. Hope that helps (for now).

Comment: @Bono have you found any solution? i cant find anything like exactRepeating

Answer (score 4):

You can separate before API 19 and after API 19. While setting alarm for the first time:

```
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), mondayIntent);
            } else {
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, mondayIntent);
            }
```

When you catch the alarm:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        rescheduleAlarm();
    }
```

You must set the alarm with

> setexact

again in rescheduleAlarm.

Hope this helps.